# Creating a filled numpy array of ones from a polygon points Python

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, points

I would be very gratefull if anyone could help me find a faster solution to my problem.

Heres the scenario:- I have a polygon of float points which I want to map to a grid. The grid cells can be different width and height not uniformed like my image shows. ie rectangular.

I have tried using Image draw but it only uses ints. Converting floats to ints means I have to scale the floats up and remove decimal to keep some precision but image draw will not work with the larger polygon of points.

Is there a more eloquent and fast way of achieving a numpy array of ones (blue) for the filled area of the polygon and zeros (red) for the rest.  I have read a little on mesh grid but cant see how it can be of use for this scenario.

Many thanks

The results from the code are

```
cols = 4
rows = 4
points = [[1535116L, 1725047L], [1535116L, 2125046L], [-464884L, 2125046L], [-464884L, 125046L]]    

bbCut = getPythonBoundBox(points)
cutWidth =  bbCut[1][0]-bbCut[0][0]
scale = float(cutWidth) / float(rows)
###Center data to origin
for p in range(len(points)):
    points[p][0] -= (bbCut[1][0] - bbCut[0][0])/2
    points[p][1] -= (bbCut[1][1] - bbCut[0][1])/2
    points[p][0] /= scale
    points[p][1] /= scale


##move points to Zero
bbCut = getPythonBoundBox(points)

for p in range(len(points)):
    points[p][0] -=bbCut[0][0]
    points[p][1] -=bbCut[0][1]

pointToTuple= []
for p in range(len(points)):
  pointToTuple.append((points[p][0], points[p][1]))

imgWidth = float(rows)
imgHeight = float(cols)

img = Image.new('L', (int(imgWidth), int(imgHeight)), 0) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon(pointToTuple, fill=1)

array =  np.reshape(list(img.getdata()), (cols, rows))

############This is the result from the array############
##If you compare this array to the coloured scaled image ive have drawn
##its missing a 1 on the second value in the first row
##and another 1 on the second row 3rd value
##I'm assuming there is some parsing happening here with float to int?                       
array([1, 0, 0, 0])
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
#########################################################

def getPythonBoundBox(points):
    bigNumber = 10e10
    xmin = bigNumber
    xmax = -bigNumber
    ymin = bigNumber
    ymax = -bigNumber
    g = []
    a = len(points)
    for i in xrange(a):
        if points[i][0] < xmin: xmin = points[i][0]
        if points[i][0] > xmax: xmax = points[i][0]
        if points[i][1] < ymin: ymin = points[i][1]
        if points[i][1] > ymax: ymax = points[i][1]
    p1 = [xmin,ymin]
    g.append(p1)
    p2 = [xmax,ymax]
    g.append(p2)
    return (g)
```

[image: polygon shape over grid]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the image?

Comment: added code thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.path.Path` has a method `contains_points`. Hence simply instantiate a path with your polygon points and then check your grid coordinates if they fall within that path. Your grid can have any resolution you want. This is controlled by `nx` and `ny` (or alternatively `dx` and `dy`) in the code below.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path

# create a matplotlib path
points = [[1535116L, 1725047L],
          [1535116L, 2125046L],
          [-464884L, 2125046L],
          [-464884L, 125046L],
          [1535116L, 1725047L]]
codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CLOSEPOLY,
         ]
path = Path(points, codes)

# check the path
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='k')
ax1.add_patch(patch)
xmin, ymin = np.min(points, axis=0)
xmax, ymax = np.max(points, axis=0)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax1.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

# create a grid
nx, ny = 1000, 1000
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pixel_coordinates = np.c_[xgrid.ravel(), ygrid.ravel()]

# find points within path
img = path.contains_points(pixel_coordinates).reshape(nx,ny)

# plot
ax2.imshow(img, cmap='gray_r', interpolation='none', origin='lower')

# repeat, but this time specify pixel widths explicitly
dx, dy = 2000, 2000
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, dx)
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax, dy)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pixel_coordinates = np.c_[xgrid.ravel(), ygrid.ravel()]
img = path.contains_points(pixel_coordinates).reshape(len(x), len(y))
ax3.imshow(img, cmap='gray_r', interpolation='none', origin='lower')
```

[image]

## UPDATE:

Ok, so this now tests the if any of the corners of each tile are within the path. For some reason, I still get another answer than the picture suggests. How sure are you, that the points that you provide are exact?

Code + image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path

# create a matplotlib path
points = [[1535116L, 1725047L],
          [1535116L, 2125046L],
          [-464884L, 2125046L],
          [-464884L, 125046L],
          [1535116L, 1725047L]]

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CLOSEPOLY,
         ]
path = Path(points, codes)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='k')
ax1.add_patch(patch)
xmin, ymin = np.min(points, axis=0)
xmax, ymax = np.max(points, axis=0)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax1.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

nx, ny = 4, 4
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pixel_centers = np.c_[xgrid.ravel(), ygrid.ravel()]

def pixel_center_to_corners(x, y, dx, dy, precision=0.):
    """
    Returns array indexed by (pixel, corner, (x,y))
    """

    # make dx and dy ever so slightly smaller,
    # such that the points fall **inside** the path (not **on** the path)
    dx -= precision
    dy -= precision

    return np.array([(x - dx/2., y - dy/2.), # lower left
                     (x + dx/2., y - dy/2.), # lower right
                     (x + dx/2., y + dy/2.), # upper right
                     (x - dx/2., y + dy/2.), # upper left
    ]).transpose([2,0,1])

# get pixel corners
dx = (xmax - xmin) / float(nx)
dy = (ymax - ymin) / float(ny)
pixel_corners = pixel_center_to_corners(pixel_centers[:,0], pixel_centers[:,1], dx, dy)

# test corners of each pixel;
# set img to True, iff any corners within path;
img = np.zeros((len(pixel_corners)))
for ii, pixel in enumerate(pixel_corners):
    is_inside_path = path.contains_points(pixel)
    img[ii] = np.any(is_inside_path)

img = img.reshape(len(x), len(y))
ax2.imshow(img, cmap='gray_r', interpolation='none', origin='lower')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a new direction. Very much appreciated. I will try the code.

Comment: Paul It seems to be giving different results to the correct results in my attached red an blue block scaled drawing. There are 4 points in the polygon but your code results a triangle? Also the code is very slow. I can imagine on larger polygons this will increase execution time.

Comment: Try the code on 4x4 array which equates to real world sizes of 50cms (pattern repeat width and height) in a triangle shape room 2m x 2.5m this is for use with a carpet fitting algorithm iam trying to create.

Comment: Sorry, forgot one LINETO, and the correct point for CLOSEPOLY. Should give a trapezoid now. Code executes in much less than a second for me. `contains_points()` is a very thin wrapper around C, iirc, so not sure how much you are going to gain by any other naive approach (you are querying for points in arbitrary shapes; if you know the shape will always be a trapezoid, you can do better). Also, how precisely can you cut your carpets? You should not run the code at a granularity exceeding your maximum precision. Going to bed now, will come back in the morning (in 8+ hours).

Comment: Paul this is brilliant works like a charm. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. If everything works for you, can you accept the answer, please?

Comment: paul sorry to be a pain there still is an issue with the first part of the code

Comment: I blame the user. ;-P What is it?

Comment: img = path.contains_points(pixel_coordinates).reshape(nx,ny). It gives wrong results compared to drawing this polygon by hand over a grid 4x4 as shown in my drawing above. There should be 3 cells outside the shape not 7 which this part of code produces. Sorry for this but this is the bit i'm also stumbling on.

Comment: OK, I think I finally understood your problem properly. Give me a couple of minutes; this will need some rewriting.

Comment: Paul these points are the same [[0L,0L], [400L,350L], [400L,400L],  [0L,400L], [0L, 0L]] also x on my cords is to right and y is down not that it makes any difference. The first and  second point is clearly cutting through the next set of cells as my sketch shows. Checking code thx matie